# TypeScript error when trying to deploy Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I just created a firebase app and written my functions in typescript

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

export const onStatementUpload = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(obj => {
  console.log('obj finalize', obj)
})
```

But on deployment:

```
src/index.ts(10,61): error TS2339: Property 'onFinalize' does not exist on type 'ObjectBuilder'.
```

I tried to install `@types/firebase-functions` but theres no such thing. How do I resolve this?

Comment: That message is saying you have an error on line 10, but your code sample doesn't even have 10 lines in it.  Is there something you're not showing here?

Comment: @DougStevenson, thats all the code there is ... but I did not paste the full stack trace my bad (I think its referring to library code) ... I already switched back to JS version ...

Comment: I didn't have any compile problems with that code. Something may be wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue as well and solved it by upgrading to the latest versions of `firebase-functions`, `firebase-admin`, and `firebase-tools` which added the `onFinalize` method (which wasn't available in previous versions).

```
# Make sure you're in your `functions` (or equivalent) directory
$ npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
$ npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Then try redeploying the app:

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions
```